# Strange Segfault on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-15.04

I'm in a Comp Sci class and my teacher uses a testing framework to grade our homeworks. I can build my assignments, but when I attempt to run, I get a segmentation fault. In LLDB, I get this backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 11993, 0x00007ffff796e990 libstdc++.so.6`std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string(), name = 'cpp_refresher', stop reason = invalid address (fault address: 0x10)
  * frame #0: 0x00007ffff796e990 libstdc++.so.6`std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
    frame #1: 0x000000000042229c cpp_refresher`MemoryAllocation::~MemoryAllocation() + 28
    frame #2: 0x0000000000422555 cpp_refresher`void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation>(MemoryAllocation*) + 21
    frame #3: 0x000000000042251f cpp_refresher`void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<MemoryAllocation*>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*) + 47
    frame #4: 0x00000000004224dd cpp_refresher`void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation*>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*) + 29
    frame #5: 0x0000000000422321 cpp_refresher`void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*, std::allocator<MemoryAllocation>&) + 33
    frame #6: 0x0000000000421847 cpp_refresher`std::vector<MemoryAllocation, std::allocator<MemoryAllocation> >::~vector() + 55
    frame #7: 0x00000000004217a5 cpp_refresher`UTTest::~UTTest() + 37
    frame #8: 0x0000000000422f49 cpp_refresher`UTTestRunner::RunSuite(std::string, std::function<void (UTTestRunner*)>) + 249
    frame #9: 0x000000000041e716 cpp_refresher`main + 118
    frame #10: 0x00007ffff6fe4a40 libc.so.6`__libc_start_main + 240
    frame #11: 0x000000000041bc09 cpp_refresher`_start + 41
```

Based on this, I think that the testing framework is causing the standard C++ libraries to segfault when it attempts to destroy a string. The interesting this is that this only occurs on Ubuntu 15.04. I can run this script on Ubuntu 14.04 and it runs perfectly.

Any ideas why this is happening only in Ubuntu 15.04?

Edit:
Here's the output from `valgrind`:

```
==2684== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2684== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2684== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2684== Command: ./cpp_refresher
==2684== 
==2684== Invalid read of size 8
==2684==    at 0x5118990: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==2684==    by 0x42229B: MemoryAllocation::~MemoryAllocation() (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x422554: void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation>(MemoryAllocation*) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x42251E: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<MemoryAllocation*>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x4224DC: void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation*>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x422320: void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*, std::allocator<MemoryAllocation>&) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x421846: std::vector<MemoryAllocation, std::allocator<MemoryAllocation> >::~vector() (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x4217A4: UTTest::~UTTest() (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x422F48: UTTestRunner::RunSuite(std::string, std::function<void (UTTestRunner*)>) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x41E715: main (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2684== 
==2684== 
==2684== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2684==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==2684==    at 0x5118990: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==2684==    by 0x42229B: MemoryAllocation::~MemoryAllocation() (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x422554: void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation>(MemoryAllocation*) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x42251E: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<MemoryAllocation*>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x4224DC: void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation*>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x422320: void std::_Destroy<MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation>(MemoryAllocation*, MemoryAllocation*, std::allocator<MemoryAllocation>&) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x421846: std::vector<MemoryAllocation, std::allocator<MemoryAllocation> >::~vector() (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x4217A4: UTTest::~UTTest() (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x422F48: UTTestRunner::RunSuite(std::string, std::function<void (UTTestRunner*)>) (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==    by 0x41E715: main (in /home/cooper/csci-2270/cpp_refresher/cpp_refresher)
==2684==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2684==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2684==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2684==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2684==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2684== 
==2684== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2684==     in use at exit: 554 bytes in 8 blocks
==2684==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 0 frees, 554 bytes allocated
==2684== 
==2684== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2684==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2684==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2684==      possibly lost: 66 bytes in 2 blocks
==2684==    still reachable: 488 bytes in 6 blocks
==2684==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2684== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2684== 
==2684== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2684== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    2684 segmentation fault (core dumped)  valgrind ./cpp_refresher
```

Comment: Run with `valgrind`,

Comment: Show the constructors, destructor and assignment operator of `class UTTest`.

Comment: Without more information - your code, in particular - we can only guess. Can you try to build a small test of your code that reproduces the problem, and post it here? That said, segfaults when deallocating usually means that you've corrupted memory. Get any pointer math wrong?

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to say anything

Comment: The malloc manpage has a few hints: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/pt/man3/malloc.3.html if you can, set the `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variable to '2'. It may catch your corruption (if that's the cause).

Comment: You can also call `mcheck()` at the beginning of your program, and then intersperse `mcheck_check_all()` calls in interesting places. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mcheck.3.html

Comment: Usually on stack overflow questions if you are confused about something, it's best to create a Minimal Verifiable Example, that someone else can copy paste and then compile. Oftentimes in the process of removing code in order to create the MVE, you learn enough to notice what is the problem yourself.

Comment: I'm unfortunately unable to provide any of the code causing the problem or make any edits. My teacher provided the unit testing framework as a static library and is not comfortable with providing the source to students. I would normally provide the MVE, but since the problem is in a library, there's not much I can do.